# Install and Configure XHProf

Tags: server, php

**Problem**

I'm trying to configure and use XHProf. I've managed to get it installed and running on my server but I get a blank page when I try to access localhost/xhprof_html

This is the general post I've been following:

http://www.grasmash.com/article/installing-xhprof-drupal#view

**Set-Up**

I'm running a fresh Ubuntu Server 13.04. Its inside an VirtualBox

(Server set-up)

I installed xhprof using:

```
 sudo pecl install -f xhprof
```

I then added the following lines to my php.ini.

```
extension=xhprof.so
xhprof.output_dir="/tmp/xhprof"
```

I then rebooted apache and tested that xhprof is running using php -m. It is.

I then moved xhprof_html from `/usr/share/php/` to `/var/www/`

But when I open `localhost/xhprof_html/index.php` I get a blank white screen.

I had something similar when I first installed drupal and the following command fixed it:

```
$ sudo chown -R www-data /var/www/drupal/
```

However I can't it to work this time.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: What do your logs say? (in `/var/log/apache`, especially the `error.log`)

Comment: @Calimo Think I fixed it. Cheers though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things seemed to fix this.

**Number One:**

Don't move xhprof_html. This seems to break it. Instead leave it where it is, or make a symlink from /var/www/xhprof_html to /usr/share/php/xhprof_html.

**Number 2**

Make sure you're testing for it correctly.

*Test 1:*

```
php -m
```

It might show up there.

But it sometimes doesn't. The other way to check is to add a php file with

```
phpinfo();
```

to `/var/www` and run it. Search for xhprof and if you find it, it's running. I didn't try the second one and was only using drupal integration to test for it, which wasn't working, so I missed that it was working.